# I get the error in my api maybe about pymysql.connect but I don't know what happened

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am making my api about output data from mysql. And I follow this link to do this but I get the Type Error. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/config/ I don't know what wrong in my code. And I try to fix this. I follow this link [How do I save database configuration without writting them on my python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734994/how-do-i-save-database-configuration-without-writting-them-on-my-python-file) but still not work.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, g, render_template, request, jsonify, json, current_app
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import flask
from global_setup import *

app = Flask(__name__)

def connect_db():
    return pymysql.connect(MY_DB_SERVER,
                            MY_DB_USER,
                            MY_DB_PASS,
                            MY_DB_DB,
                            MY_DB_PORT,
                            charset='utf8',
                            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

def get_db():
    '''Opens a new database connection per request.'''      
    if not hasattr(g, 'db'):
        g.db = connect_db()
    return g.db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db(error):
    '''Closes the database connection at the end of request.''' 
    if hasattr(g, 'db'):
        g.db.close()

@app.route('/api/CRM',methods = ['POST'])
def index1():
    cursor = get_db().cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from customer")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    return jsonify(rows)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

The error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2021 18:40:29] "POST /api/CRM HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2088, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/Teemo.Tsui/git/KF/api_123.py", line 34, in index1
    cursor = get_db().cursor()
  File "/home/Teemo.Tsui/git/KF/api_123.py", line 23, in get_db
    g.db = connect_db()
  File "/home/Teemo.Tsui/git/KF/api_123.py", line 18, in connect_db
    cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 6 positional arguments (and 2 keyword-only arguments) were given
```

This is my global_setup.py

```
MY_DB_SERVER = ""
MY_DB_USER = ""
MY_DB_PASS = ""
MY_DB_DB = ""
MY_DB_PORT = 3306
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `pymysql.connect` args need to be named, so:

```
def connect_db():
    return pymysql.connect(host=MY_DB_SERVER,
                            user=MY_DB_USER,
                            password=MY_DB_PASS,
                            database=MY_DB_DB,
                            port=MY_DB_PORT,
                            charset='utf8',
                            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```